# Why is proton called 质子 and charge called 电荷?

Tags: etymology

For instance, in medical terminology, we can tease out the meaning from the words. But I cannot tell why we use 质 for proton and 荷 for charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質子 means 有質量的粒子 (*subatomic particle with mass*, in contrast with electrons which comparably have very little mass), where 質量 means *mass* (specifically in the field of physics). Although neutrons also have mass, they're called 中子.

荷 generically means *load, burden*, and in 電荷 it literally means *electric load* > *electric charge*.

Comment: 中子 is named so just because it's not electronic

Comment: Or rather, it has a _neutral_ charge (compare 中立 for the general meaning of "neutrality")

Answer (score 3):

质 in Chinese mean inseparable (不可分割) such as 质数 （prime number）

Another explaination, 质：事物的根本特性.

https://www.zhihu.com/question/38322079